# conditionalPanel and recaptchaUI not working together in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, recaptcha

For my shinyapp, I am currently trying to implement a conditionalPanel in the sidebar.
It is working fine, if I don't use recaptcha button at the end for submission. But with recaptcha button, the conditional Panel does not work.

I am using the [shinyCAPTCHA](https://github.com/carlganz/shinyCAPTCHA) library for this.

I also tried attaching recaptha to both the conditional panels separately, but even then the conditionalpanel functionality does not work.

I guess it has something to do with the way recaptchaUI is coded in terms of location of the UI box, however I am not sure how to solve the issue.

GIFs of usage are attached here:

1. Without recaptcha, conditional panel works fine
   [image: Conditional panel working without recaptcha]
2. With recaptcha button added, the panel for "request" input choice just disappears.
   [image: Conditional Panel not working with recaptcha]

The code is here:  (you will need to generate and enter a sitekey to run this :| )

```
# setup -------------------------------------------------------------------
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)



# Define UI for application 

ui <- fluidPage(
    div(h1("Application Title"),
        h3("Application description"),align = "center"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # div(
            h4("Register/Request for a new site"),
            shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
            radioButtons("registerorrequest",
                         "Register or Request: ",
                         choiceValues = list("register","request"),
                         choiceNames = c(
                             "Register your entity",
                             "Request for an entity"
                         ),
                         selected = NULL),
            
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.registerorrequest == 'register'",
                numericInput("A","Input A for register",value = 0),
                radioButtons("B","Input B for register: ",
                             choices = c(
                                 "X",
                                 "Y",
                                 "Z",
                                 "Other"
                             ),selected = NULL),
                radioButtons("C", "Input C for register: ",
                             choices = c(
                                 "more choices",
                                 "other choices"),selected = NULL),
                radioButtons("D","Input D for register:",
                             choices = c("Yes","No"),selected = NULL)
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.registerorrequest == 'request'",
                radioButtons("P", "Input P for request: ",
                             choices = c(
                                 "some choices",
                                 "some more choices"),selected = NULL),
            ),
            div(textInput("additionalinput","Any additional input",value = ""),
                recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "enterSitekey"),
                uiOutput("humansOnly"),
                style = "font-family:Arial"),
            width = 4
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel()))

    # Define server logic 
    server <- function(input, output) {}
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any input to solve this would be of great help to me. Thank you!